# Issue with FTP Transfer Script for CRON

Tags: ftp, rackspace

I'm trying to get a Backup Script working for rackspace. The final part where it sends the backup to a server isnt working.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Set information specific to your site
webroot="/mnt/stor08-wc1-ord1/666666/www.mysite.com/"
db_host="mysql51-900.wc1.ord1.stabletransit.com"
db_user="666666_backup"
db_password="PassBackup2015"
db_name="666666_wealth"

#Set the date and name for the backup files
date=`date '+%F-%H-%M'`
backupname="backup.$date.tar.gz"

#Dump the mysql database

mysqldump -h $db_host -u $db_user --password="$db_password" $db_name > $webroot/db_backup.sql

#Backup Site
tar -czpvf $webroot/sitebackup.tar.gz $webroot/web/content/

#Compress DB and Site backup into one file
tar --exclude 'sitebackup' --remove-files -czpvf $webroot/$backupname $webroot/sitebackup.tar.gz $webroot/db_backup.sql

HOST='172.0.0.1'
USER='FILESERV\ftp'
PASSWD='PassBackup2015!'

ftp $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWD
cd $webroot
put $backupname
quit
END_SCRIPT

exit 0
```

Comment: Have you tried making sure that the FTP user/pass and the commands work outside the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *may* need to use `ftp -n` to prevent auto-login from occurring. Using auto-login with the `user` command often causes problems.

In other words, something like:

```
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
user $USER $PASSWD
cd $webroot
put $backupname
quit
END_SCRIPT
```